# Is there a way to save a value across multiple executions of a C++ application?

Tags: c++, variables, save, global-variables

For example,

```
int var;
int main() {
    if(var==5) {
        cout<<"Program has been run before"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        var = 5;
        cout<<"First run"<<endl;
    }
}
```

This would print First run the first time, and Program has been run before each time after. Is this possible at all?

EDIT: a file won't work, is there any other method?

Comment: The only standard mechanism is to use a file. Other solutions will be platform dependent.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux do you happen to know any platform dependent solutions?

Comment: Only plain file won't work (will databases work) ? What is your target platform ? Linux ? Windows ?

Comment: @nefas databases would be a last resort. Linux, RHEL 6.

Comment: Do you need to save the value even after reboot ? Can you modify your profile (write to ``.profile``, ``.bashrc`` ...) ?

Comment: Can you fork a process?

Comment: Save to a file is cross-platform. On Windows you could also save to the registry.

Comment: Registry is files, but then on Linux pretty much everything is files.

Comment: Out of interest, why won't a file work?

Answer (score 7):

You need to save that counter somewhere outside of the application. The variables are stored in the memory that is reserved for the process. So when your process dies, the values in memory are gone as well.

If a flat file does not work, other options could be a database or perhaps even a separate daemon that keeps track on the run times of a certain application. But if you want to persist the counter over power cycles, you will need to save that data value somewhere in persistent memory (e.g. hard drive)

Comment: I noticed earlier that this answer got it's downvotes very early, when it was still only 1 or 2 sentences. People likely downvoted the original incomplete answer and never checked back. Initially, your answer just said "You need to save that counter somewhere outside of the application."

Comment: Ah right, they indeed draw fast then. It was matter of seconds. But thanks, I thought the downvotes were for the rev 1.

Comment: I've heard some people recommend posting answers as fast as possible, as a "trick" to getting more rep, and completing the answer with edits afterwards. Maybe it works with other communities, but the c++ community is quite ruthless when dispensing downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's the gist of it:

If the kernel you are running doesn't provide files you need to give specific details about what kernel and/or device you are using and if you need to store them between "reboots", since not being able to crate files sounds quite specifics.

If you don't have any flash/hdd/ssd or other type of "hard" to save data to, saving values between executions is impossible, you can't save values in RAM due to its dynamic nature.

What you could do is:

a) Write your own primitive fs management tool, if your architecture only ever runs your app this should be easy since you don't need to make a lot of checks, but you need to have a static memory of sorts to store the bytes to

b) At the end of executing re-compile the initial program and replace the values you want to replace with the ones present in your current program

c) Save the values in some external variables using a a shell:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   putenv("EXTERNAL_STATE=" + my_variable);
```

d) Send the state you wish to save over the network to a machine that has a filesystem and read/write it from there.

e) Have a separate application that runs in a while and listens for input from the console. when it receives sets input it runs your program with said variable as the parameter, when your program returns it outputs the variable and the "parent" application reads it and sets it internally

Comment: For the export solution, wouldn't it be better to export the variable outside of the program and only modify it from the program ? From what I remember, ``export`` export the variable to the child. The variable, if not exported by the program parent would be removed once the program stop. (I'm not sure of that, sorry if I'm wrong)

Comment: Possibly so, added a more explicit way of doing it, but env variable and the way they are handled are system specific anyway. I'm not even sure its part of posix

Answer (score 1):

I came out with the idea of using *shared memory* from boost libraries.

The concept is that the first time the program runs, it creates another process of itself, just called with a specific parameter (yes, it's a sort of a fork, but in this way we have a portable solution). The parallel process just handles the initialization of the shared memory, and waits for a termination signal.

The major downside of the following implementation is that, in theory, the shared memory of the *client* (not the manager) could be opened before the *server* (which handles the shared memory) has completed the initialization.

Oh, I am just printing the index of the run in base 0, just for demonstration. Here the code.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <csignal>

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

static constexpr const char* daemonizer_string = "--daemon";
static constexpr const char* shared_memory_name = "shared_memory";

static std::mutex waiter_mutex;
static std::condition_variable waiter_cv;

struct shared_data_type
{
    std::size_t count = 0;
};

extern "C"
void signal_handler(int)
{
    waiter_cv.notify_one();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

    if(argc == 2 and std::strcmp(argv[1], daemonizer_string) == 0)
    {
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove() { bi::shared_memory_object::remove("shared_memory"); }
            ~shm_remove() { bi::shared_memory_object::remove("shared_memory"); }
        } shm_remover;

        bi::shared_memory_object shm(bi::create_only, shared_memory_name, bi::read_write);

        shm.truncate(sizeof(shared_data_type));
        bi::mapped_region region(shm, bi::read_write);
        void* region_address = region.get_address();
        shared_data_type* shared_data = new (region_address) shared_data_type;

        std::signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(waiter_mutex);
            waiter_cv.wait(lock);
        }

        shared_data->~shared_data_type();
    }
    else
    {
        bi::shared_memory_object shm;
        try
        {
            shm = bi::shared_memory_object(bi::open_only, shared_memory_name, bi::read_write);
        }
        catch(std::exception&)
        {
            using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
            bp::spawn(argv[0], daemonizer_string);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
            shm = bi::shared_memory_object(bi::open_only, shared_memory_name, bi::read_write);
        }

        bi::mapped_region region(shm, bi::read_write);
        shared_data_type& shared_data = *static_cast<shared_data_type*>(region.get_address());
        std::cout << shared_data.count++ << '\n'; 
    }
}
```